# Realtek ALC887-VD popping sound xbmc

Tags: sound, realtek, optical

I have the following hardware:
Asus E45M1-M Pro based htpc, Yamaha RX-V550, LG 50PA6500.
Connections: sound: htpc->yamaha via s/pdif optical, video: htpc->lg tv via hdmi.
And software:
Ubuntu 12.10 minimal server (so x64) 3.6.3-030603-generic kernel  installed, XBMC Frodo more or less following [THIS](http://youresuchageek.blogspot.de/2012/06/xbmc-install-and-config-howto-for-linux.html) method.

I experience strange, annoying sound "pops" while watching a movie. Specially if there are loud effects.
Stereo, 5.1, DD, DTS, DTS HD, so the failure exists by every format.
I tried to remove the alsa-base, no luck.

I had Asus AT3IONT-I Deluxe with just the same ALC887 chip, and with 12.04 x86 XBMC Eden i had no problems at all.
Funny is that regarding asus homepage the E45 board has an Anti-pop Function. :)

[lspci pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1648815/)

Every help and suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks, best regards

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Tried a bunch of things to fix it, finally actually did:

Outside of XBMC:
- made sure my pulseaudio / alsa default system volume levels were at the "unamplified" setting.  This didn't do it, but will distort the sound in other ways

Inside of XBMC: 
 - During movie playback, get the bottom menu up, and click the speaker on the right.  This will take you to an audio configuration page.  First option is volume.  It is set with the slider all the way to the right, and apparently this is 0db (unamplified).  I lowered the volume to -3db (mostly all the way up, but not quite) -- the pops disappeared.

Looks like XBMC isn't exactly sure of where it's amplifying sound and causing clipping (the pops).  Turning it down just a bit still left it fairly loud on the TV, but without pops.

Comment: well thanks! i'll give a try!
however the xbmc wont let me downcrease the sound if i play passthrough audio (which happens of corse 9/10 times, since the movies are all in ac3/dts)
i'll check the alsa/pulseaudio settings! thanks